# If I check all checkboxes the select all checkbox should automatically checked and vice-versa in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I checked the check all checkbox at top then all checkbox are getting checked. But problem comes when i check every checkbox individually the select all checkbox should be automatically be checked and vice-versa.
Here is the code :

```
    <html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <p>Click the table headers to change the sorting order:</p>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
    <p>
      <button type="button" ng-click="remove($index)">Delete Selected</button>
    </p>

    <table border="1" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
        </th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Sl no</th>
        <th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="orderByMe('country')">Country</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:myOrderBy">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.select" ng-click="xsetting(x)" />
        </td>
        <td>{{x.select}}</td>
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.country}}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" ng-click="Delete(x)">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', ['$scope', 'filterFilter', function($scope, filterFilter) {
      $scope.names = [{
        name: 'Jani',
        country: 'Norway'
      }, {
        name: 'Carl',
        country: 'Sweden'
      }, {
        name: 'Margareth',
        country: 'England'
      }, {
        name: 'Hege',
        country: 'Norway'
      }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        country: 'Denmark'
      }, {
        name: 'Gustav',
        country: 'Sweden'
      }, {
        name: 'Birgit',
        country: 'Denmark'
      }, {
        name: 'Mary',
        country: 'England'
      }, {
        name: 'Kai',
        country: 'Norway'
      }];

      //for sorting the rows    
      $scope.orderByMe = function(x) {
          $scope.myOrderBy = x;
        }
        //single row deletion
      $scope.Delete = function(x) {
        $scope.names.splice($scope.names.indexOf(x), 1);
      };
      //selecting all checkboxes in the table
      $scope.checkAll = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.names, function(x) {
          x.select = $scope.selectAll;
        });
      };
      //for selecting and deleting checked items
      $scope.remove = function() {
        $scope.names = filterFilter($scope.names, function(x) {
          return !x.select;
        });
      };

    }]);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

here is the link to plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/LFShX3PTEITLaN7fSElX?p=preview

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `ng-checked` on your select All checkbox, like:

```
 ng-checked="allChecked()"
```

where `allChecked` is a function in controller which finds out whether all names have been selected or not. Something like,

```
$scope.allChecked = function() {
  return $scope.names.filter(obj => obj.select).length === $scope.names.length
}
```

[**working example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/RnmlqAO7js8Xo7QZnXoe?p=preview)

**EDIT**: Without arrow function,

```
$scope.allChecked = function() {
  var selectedNames = $scope.names.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.select
  });
  return selectedNames.length === $scope.names.length
}
```

Comment: I'm working with angularjs in eclipse. So in eclipse using   "=>" symbol is showing error. Any suggestions what can I do?

Comment: Yes, Actually yesterday it was not working. but today when i tried it worked with that symbol. Is their any problem in eclipse. Its showing error for that symbol but working fine. I have another question here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800095/while-editing-a-row-how-does-the-cancel-button-will-work-and-if-i-want-to-edit

Answer (score 1):

Below given code may help you . Once your are checking or unchecking any All Checkbox from top most checkbox then you done code to check All. But for Individual checkbox's on  ng-click you call a function but not implemented this function. Here is your updated code .

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <p>Click the table headers to change the sorting order:</p>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
    <p>
      <button type="button" ng-click="remove($index)">Delete Selected</button>
    </p>

    <table border="1" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
        </th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Sl no</th>
        <th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="orderByMe('country')">Country</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:myOrderBy">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.select" ng-click="xsetting(x)" />
        </td>
        <td>{{x.select}}</td>
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.country}}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" ng-click="Delete(x)">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', ['$scope', 'filterFilter', function($scope, filterFilter) {
      $scope.names = [{
        name: 'Jani',
        country: 'Norway'
      }, {
        name: 'Carl',
        country: 'Sweden'
      }, {
        name: 'Margareth',
        country: 'England'
      }, {
        name: 'Hege',
        country: 'Norway'
      }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        country: 'Denmark'
      }, {
        name: 'Gustav',
        country: 'Sweden'
      }, {
        name: 'Birgit',
        country: 'Denmark'
      }, {
        name: 'Mary',
        country: 'England'
      }, {
        name: 'Kai',
        country: 'Norway'
      }];

      //for sorting the rows    
      $scope.orderByMe = function(x) {
          $scope.myOrderBy = x;
        }
        //single row deletion
      $scope.Delete = function(x) {
        $scope.names.splice($scope.names.indexOf(x), 1);
      };
      //selecting all checkboxes in the table
      $scope.checkAll = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.names, function(x) {
          x.select = $scope.selectAll;
        });
      };

      $scope.xsetting = function(x) {
          $scope.selectAll = true;
          angular.forEach($scope.names, function(v, k) {
            if (!v.checked) {
              $scope.selectAll = false;
            }
          });
        }
        //for selecting and deleting checked items
      $scope.remove = function() {
        $scope.names = filterFilter($scope.names, function(x) {
          return !x.select;
        });
      };

    }]);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is http://plnkr.co/edit/TmF4jFtRmFFKoYngSYpq?p=preview and it is working.

Comment: Actually it is working partially. When i check all individual checkbox then the select all checkbox is not getting selected rather if I check select all check box and then i uncheck one, Its working

Comment: Can you tell me what problem you are facing now ?

Comment: Sorry KP Chundawat. Glad for helping. I thought you are tanmay. Actually when you click check all at top...all checkbox get selected and after that when you uncheck a single check box and then check it again it is not working

Comment: You can use my code, It is working .If It help you then kindly also accept this as answer . Happy Coding :) .

Comment: Their is a error in your code. Why don't you understand.just check it. 1.Click select all checkbox 2.Uncheck any single row and again check it. 3.Now you can see the select all check box is not been checked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143399/discussion-between-neo-abi1000-and-kp-chundawat).