# While editing a row , How does the cancel button will work and If I want to edit selected items at a time with edit button in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the code below

```
    <html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <p>Click the table headers to change the sorting order:</p>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
    <p>
      <button type="button" ng-click="remove($index)">Delete Selected</button>
      <button type="button" ng-click="">Edit Selected</button>
    </p>

    <table border="1" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll()" ng-checked="allChecked()" />
        </th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Sl no</th>
        <th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="orderByMe('country')">Country</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:myOrderBy">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.select" ng-click="xsetting(x)" />
        </td>
        <td>{{x.select}}</td>
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>
          <div ng-hide="editData[x.id]">{{x.name}}</div>
          <div ng-show="editData[x.id]"><input type="text" ng-model="x.name" /></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div ng-hide="editData[x.id]">{{x.country}}</div>
          <div ng-show="editData[x.id]"><input type="text" ng-model="x.country" /></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" ng-click="Delete(x)">Delete</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button ng-hide="editData[x.id]" ng-click="edit(x)">Edit</button>
          <button ng-show="editData[x.id]" ng-click="update(x)">Update</button>
          <button ng-show="editData[x.id]" ng-click="cancel(x)">Cancel</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', ['$scope', 'filterFilter', function($scope, filterFilter) {
      $scope.names = [{
        name: 'Jani',
        country: 'Norway',
        id: '0'
      }, {
        name: 'Carl',
        country: 'Sweden',
        id: '1'
      }, {
        name: 'Margareth',
        country: 'England',
        id: '2'
      }, {
        name: 'Hege',
        country: 'Norway',
        id: '3'
      }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        country: 'Denmark',
        id: '4'
      }, {
        name: 'Gustav',
        country: 'Sweden',
        id: '5'
      }, {
        name: 'Birgit',
        country: 'Denmark',
        id: '6'
      }, {
        name: 'Mary',
        country: 'England',
        id: '7'
      }, {
        name: 'Kai',
        country: 'Norway',
        id: '8'
      }];

      //for sorting the rows    
      $scope.orderByMe = function(x) {
          $scope.myOrderBy = x;
      }
      //single row deletion
      $scope.Delete = function(x) {
        $scope.names.splice($scope.names.indexOf(x), 1);
      };
      //selecting all checkboxes in the table
      $scope.checkAll = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.names, function(x) {
          x.select = $scope.selectAll;
      });
      };
      //select all checkbox automatically checked if all individual rows checked
      $scope.allChecked = function() {
        return $scope.names.filter(obj => obj.select).length === $scope.names.length
      }
      //for selecting and deleting checked items
      $scope.remove = function() {
        $scope.names = filterFilter($scope.names, function(x) {
          return !x.select;
        });
      };

      //edit the rows using edit button
      $scope.editData = {};

      for (var i = 0, length = $scope.names.length; i < length; i++) {
        $scope.editData[$scope.names[i].id] = false;
      };

      $scope.edit = function(x) {
        $scope.editData[x.id] = true;
      };

      $scope.update = function(x) {
        $scope.editData[x.id] = false;
      };

      $scope.cancel = function(x) {

      };


    }]);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

How will i write a reset function for cancel button and after that how can I check individual rows and edit all at a time. Can some one help me with this?
Here is the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/w6OvIO77PiWPIxWl1b5f?p=preview

Comment: Okay I will make you a fiddle with the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle for the answer

https://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/edkrLbuu/
used copy function to achieve this

```
  $scope.orgNames = angular.copy($scope.names);

  $scope.edit = function(x,$index) {
    x.edit = true;
  };

  $scope.update = function(x,$index) {
    x.edit = false;
    var index = $scope.names.findIndex(i => i.id==x.id);
    var orgIndex = $scope.orgNames.findIndex(i => i.id==x.id);
    $scope.orgNames[orgIndex] = angular.copy(x)
  };

  $scope.cancel = function(x,$index) {
    x.edit = false;
    var index = $scope.names.findIndex(i=> i.id==x.id);
    var orgIndex = $scope.orgNames.findIndex(i => i.id==x.id);
    $scope.names[index] = angular.copy($scope.orgNames[orgIndex])
  };
```

Comment: actually the cancel function is working but the cancel button is not getting hidden after that. And how to check individual rows and use the edit selected button for that

Comment: I have fixed the cancel thing.
For the second question you need to put edit =true in each row. I will make them too.

Comment: Can you explain please how did you do?? Thanks

Comment: Sure. If the answer is okay please mark it too.. I will add comments on the fiddle

Comment: Their is a error. When you sort the data by names and then by country and when click edit for a single row and do some editing and then cancel it, the data is getting updated

Comment: Okey in that case the index is changing , No issues we can fix it.

Comment: Can you please recheck the fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/edkrLbuu/

Comment: can you please explain what did you did in the update and cancel function and why did you use debugger word? How do you think man. can you tell me where should i refer to be like you in angularjs? Do i also need to be strong in javascript also as i know only basics

Answer (score 1):

About cancel function for the sake of brevity this is very rough code but you can understand main idea (it's part of your code from plunker but with some changes):

```
 //edit the rows using edit button
      $scope.editData = {};
      $scope.tempData = {};

      for (var i = 0, length = $scope.names.length; i < length; i++) {
        $scope.editData[$scope.names[i].id] = false;
      };

      $scope.edit = function(x) {
        $scope.tempData.name = x.name;
        $scope.tempData.country = x.country;

        $scope.editData[x.id] = true;
      };

      $scope.update = function(x) {
        $scope.editData[x.id] = false;
      };

      $scope.cancel = function(x) {
          x.name = $scope.tempData.name;
          x.country = $scope.tempData.country;
          $scope.tempData = {};
          $scope.editData[x.id] = false;
      };
```

For second question:
Change ng-click

```
<button type="button" ng-click="editSelected()">Edit Selected</button>
```

and add this function:

```
$scope.editSelected = function(){
      for (var i = 0, length = $scope.names.length; i < length; i++) {
        if($scope.names[i].select)
          $scope.editData[$scope.names[i].id] = true;
      };
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man. And how to check individual rows and use the edit selected button for that. Can you tell me why you used tempData

Comment: I use tempData for restore previous values if user click Cancel button. Because when user edit fields it change directly model. About second question, do you want check the row and activate edit mode?

Comment: Yes if I check all rows and click edit selected button then all rows can active for editing. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I'm changed the answer.

Comment: Bu when I click edit selected and then i click cancel, the data is getting removed